# Program will not run when called with start

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code, but when I run it, nothing happens.

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\QLC\shared\jre1.6\bin" javaw.exe
exit
```

Comment: what is that you are trying to do here and what error are your facing?

Comment: no error is there, but it not started program,

Comment: can you post your program code snippet?

Comment: what is code snippet?

Comment: It's worth noting that you _must_ provide a .class file as an argument for javaw.exe; when you run javaw.exe by itself, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

`Start` considers the first set of quotes it encounters to be the desired title of the window, regardless of where in the command those quotes are located.

To get around this, add a second set of quotes.

```
start "" /d "C:\Program Files\QLC\shared\jre1.6\bin" javaw.exe
exit
```

Also, `javaw.exe` by itself will not do anything. You must provide the program with a .class file or a .jar file to run.

Comment: i have done like,
start "" /d "C:\Program Files\QLC\shared\jre1.6\bin" javaw.exe
exit